# How to always display MPxNodes

Tags: c++, nodes, maya

In Maya API, MPxLocatorNodes allow to draw OpenGL on the viewport.
However, when the locator position is not on the screen, then its draw function will not be called. How to have the draw function been called all the time, even when the locator is not on the screen ?

Comment: You cannot, it is the way Maya is designed to work with locators. If you tell me why you need the draw() function to be called while you will see nothing in the Maya viewport, I can take a look in the Maya code and give you a hint. When I wrote my Kinect plug-in I used a thread to force evaluation for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by either returning False in the isBounded function, or by extending the bounding box size in the boundingBox() function.